# Segmentation fault on fprintf

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I have this simple piece of code:

```
void create(){
    char *username;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("~/retele/PROIECT/user.txt", "w");
    printf("Type username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", username);
    fclose(fptr);   

}
```

and I don't get it, why do I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: `username` doesn't point anywhere yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point:

```
scanf("%s", username);
```

the pointer variable `username` is not initialised, it points at an unpredictable memory part. You are basically saying "Please write the input anywhere into memory." and should not be surprised that the system complains, actually you should consider yourself lucky that it complains, there are much harder to debug possible reactions.
(You are also ignoring the return value of scanf, which would be the only way that the system could give you information about other ways of failing to do as you expect.)
The pointer especially does not point to any memory area usable for the purpose of storing input.
You can change that by using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a pointer named username which of type char. But you forgot to assign a memory for that pointer.

```
username = (char*)malloc(any_size_you_want);
```